# mysql select from 2 different tables and return either highest price

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query that I'm trying to figure out.

Basically I have table 1 cols:   estate agent, price, location, bungalow, cottage

and I have table 2 cols:         estate agent, price, location, penthouse, duplex

As you can see these tables are very different.

I need a query to select all cols from table 1 or 2 depending on which has the highest price.  For example:

```
    SELECT  *  FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.price = table2.price ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 1,1;
```

Comment: Table 1 or table 2 or both of them ? you can use an agGregate function **Max**

Comment: Should I use ORDER BY a.priceInt, b.priceInt....  why in my database are 1 or 11 being appended to the column names.

Comment: @menai   I need to select all columns from table 1 or 2 depending on which has the highest price... not combine them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the tables are so similar, you could UNION them, then sort the result descending and get the higher price.

```
(SELECT * FROM table1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM table2)
ORDER BY price DESC
LIMIT 1
```

You would need to specify the columns explicitly if you want to give them aliases.

---

Re your followup question:

If you have a few columns different between the two tables, and you want to preserve them, you need to move away from `SELECT *` and name all the columns explicitly.

```
(SELECT estate agent, price, location, bungalow, cottage, NULL AS penthouse, NULL AS duplex
 FROM table1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT estate agent, price, location, NULL, NULL, penthouse, duplex
 FROM table2)
ORDER BY price DESC
LIMIT 1
```

You don't need to give aliases in the second subquery because column names are always determined by the first query of a UNION. Even if you do declare column aliases in the second query, they'll be ignored.

Comment: works like a charm... My example code (for giving code sake)  returned a  row combining all the columns.  What I needed was UNION ALL

Comment: From a front-end perspective, if its either table 1 or table 2, how can you detect if for example cottage has a value.  For brevity sake its either 0 or 1.  If it was a flat would specifying that column return null?

Answer (score 0):

try this:
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2
ORDER BY price desc)x 
LIMIT 1;